# Problema C# winforms LinQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, linq, datagrid

Estoy trabajando CodeFirst y tengo la siguiente tabla en mi BD y cuando la quiero mostrar el query en un DataGridView trae todos campos, pero quiero mostrar solo 2, exactamente el nombre y el precio. Que debo modificar en la consulta Linq ?

```
var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.Category).OrderBy(p => p.Category.Name).ThenBy(p => p.Name);

dgvProductos.DataSource = products.ToList();
```

[image: **introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí**]

Esta es la clase

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Categoría")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Producto")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 3)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Precio de alquiler")]
    public decimal RentalPrice { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 4)]
    [Display(Name = "Comentarios")]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }       

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

La consulta que haces con sintaxis lambda la debes cambiar a Linq para que solo obtengas los campos que deseas:

```
var products = from p in db.Products
               join c in db.Category on p.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId 
               orderby c.Name, p.Name
               select new {
                   p.Name, P.RentalPrice
               };
```

Dada tu consulta, no veo necesario hacer el `join` a categorías ya que no estás haciendo uso de esos datos, propongo que tu consulta quede de la siguiente manera:

```
var products = from p in db.Products
               orderby p.Name ascending
               select new {
                   p.Name, P.RentalPrice
               };
```

Comment: Solo puntualizar que no es necesario cambiar la sintaxis de lambda, simplemente puede añadir un `Select(x=> new {x.Name,x.RentalPrice});`